# How does an almost complex structure on a manifold induce an orientation?

Tags: manifolds, complex-geometry

I have read that given a smooth even dimensional manifold $M$ with an almost complex structure $J$, then $M$ is orientable and there is a canonical choice of orientation.  Why is this the case? How does one construct the orientation?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1817959/24563