# Elementary proof that a non-orientable manifold of real dimension $2$ does not admit a quasi-complex structure.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Is there an easy proof that a non-orientable real surface $X$ does not admit a quasi-complex structure?

The proof I know is to observe that any quasi-complex structure on a real surface
$X$ necessarily satisfies the integrability condition
$$[T_X^{0,1}, T_X^{0,1}] \subset T_X^{0,1}$$
of the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem, because $T_X^{0,1}$ is a $1$-dimensional complex vector bundle, and the bracket $[-,-]$ is alternating, i.e. it vanishes on $T_X^{0,1}$. So by the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem, $X$ admits a complex structure, and complex manifolds have to be orientable.

However, the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem is a deep theorem and feels a bit overkill. Also I don't really *see* why there cannot be a quasi-complex structure. Is there a more elementary proof to convince myself?

Comment: Have you consulted some of the past questions on this around here? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817959/almost-complex-manifolds-are-orientable) has one nice proof (the +22 answer).

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the reference! That is indeed a nice proof!